# Successfully give multiple text fields the same value

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, afnetworking, uitextinput

My app uses text fields to let users login. The login viewcontroller has a total of 4 text field IBOutlets:

```
IBOutlet UITextField* fldUsername;

IBOutlet UITextField* fldPassword;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField*  nicknameTextField;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField* secretCodeTextField;
```

How can one properly string the `nickNameTextField` with whatever value the `fldUsername` text field gets from the user? If `fldUsername` gets a "JohnnyAppleseed" value from the user, I want `nicknameTextField` to get the exact same value simultaneously. Proper way to achieve this using obkective c?

Thanks a lot for the updates @Jamil: I got it to work with the following line of code:

```
NSMutableDictionary* params =[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:command, @"command", _nicknameTextField.text = fldUsername.text, @"username", hashedPassword, @"password", nil];
```

Since it was already being used in for the login function, it worked by adding `_nicknameTextField.text = fldUsername.text`

Comment: do you need this, when updated whole "JohnnyAppleseed"?

Comment: Or each letter of "JohnnyAppleseed"

Comment: Hi @Jamil, I'd like each letter so that while the user is typing, the whole value is there visibly. I think that would be better

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can achieve this, by implementing this delegate method.

**first you need set tag of all 4 text field** OR you have to check your current textfield other way

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string;{
   //check this  '**textField**' is **fldUsername** textfield 

     if(fldUsername.tag == textField.tag){
       fldUsername.text =  textField.text;
       nicknameTextField.text =  textField.text;  //override what ever it's prevous value
   }
 }
```

Comment: If you already have pointers to the text fields, you don't need to use tags; just use the pointers.